# Help with str_replace()

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I'm cleaning a string removing strings in this array:

```
$regex = array("subida", " de"," do", " da", "em", " na", " no", "blitz");
```

And this is the str_replace i'm using:

```
for($i=0;$i<8;$i++){
    $twit = str_replace($regex[$i],'', $twit);
}
```

how do I make it only remove a word if it's exactly the word in string, I mean, I have the following phrase:
"#blitz na subida do alfabarra blitz"
it will return me:
"# alfabarra",
I don't want the first "blitz" to  be removed because it has a hash "#", i want it to output:
"#blitz alfabarra", is it possible ? thanks

Comment: The name of your variable (`$regex`) is misleading as you are not using regular expressions at all. And actually, `str_replace` accepts and array, so you *could* do `$twit = str_replace($regex,'', $twit);`

Answer (score 5):

This assumes that none of your strings have `/` in them. If so, run `preg_quote()` explicitly with `/` as the second argument.

It also assumes you want to match the words, so I trimmed each word.

```
$words = array("subida", " de"," do", " da", "em", " na", " no", "blitz");

$words = array_map('trim', $words);

$words = array_map('preg_quote', $words);

$str = preg_replace('/\b[^#](?:' . implode('|', $words) . ')\b/', '', $str);
```

[Codepad](http://codepad.org/1qot7bdy).

Comment: Slight caveat with regular expression: could remove words like "ablitz" due to character class. Regex-fu failed me here, so used array_diff on the words instead.

Comment: @cbuckley Hmm, you are right. I'll have to have another think :)

Answer (score 1):

After failing to come up with a catch-all regex solution, the following may be useful:

```
$words = array("subida", " de", " do", " da", "em", " na", " no", "blitz");
$words = array_map('trim', $words);

$str = '#blitz *blitz ablitz na subida do alfabarra blitz# blitz blitza';

$str_words = explode(' ', $str);
$str_words = array_diff($str_words, $words);
$str = implode(' ', $str_words);
var_dump($str);
```

Gets round a few complications with word boundaries in regex-based solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for($i=0; $i<$regex('count'); $i++){
    foreach($regex[$i] as $key) {
        if ( is_string($key) ) {
            $twit = str_replace($regex[$i],'', $twit);
        }
    }
}
```